# Push segue to scrollview display error

Tags: xcode, scrollview, push

maybe this is a rather simple question. I don't know. I searched the forums for an answer but couldn't find one. I have two views. From a tablecell I push to a second view which contains a scrollview (960 x 455). This scrollview is centered when loaded.

Whenever I push into this view, the left part of the scroll which shouldn't be visible right away shows up for a few seconds. The same happens when I push back. Is there a way to push into the second view and only show the center of the scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that this is occurring because the view is being loaded and then afterwards the position is being set which can take a while when the view is first being loaded as their other things being processed before setting the position.

I am presuming you are using interface builder if so I recommend setting the UIScrollViews visible/hidden property to true in there then in the viewDidLoad method setting it's position to centre after which you can set it to be visible again.